# What different between default and clientDefault function in Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I use Exposed library in Kotlin project.
On my table declaration, I have a column like this:

`val updatedDate = datetime("updated_dt").clientDefault { DateTime.now() }`

What different if I replace clientDefault function by default as below:

`val updatedDate = datetime("updated_dt").default(DateTime.now())`

I've see source code of this two function, but still no idea.

`clientDefault` function:

```
fun <T:Any> Column<T>.clientDefault(defaultValue: () -> T): Column<T> {
        this.defaultValueFun = defaultValue
        this.dbDefaultValue = null
        return this
    }
```

`default` function:

```
fun <T:Any> Column<T>.default(defaultValue: T): Column<T> {
        this.dbDefaultValue = SqlExpressionBuilder.run {
            asLiteral(defaultValue)
        }
        this.defaultValueFun = { defaultValue }
        return this
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference in general is (going just by the code you quoted):

1. `default` only accepts a fixed `T` and will generate a `DEFAULT` SQL clause;
2. `clientDefault` accepts a function generating a `T` (so it can return different results for different rows) and doesn't generate a `DEFAULT`.

So `default(DateTime.now())` is nearly certainly not what you want; it'll generate something like `DEFAULT "2019-10-10T..."` with the datetime it's called, not `DEFAULT NOW()`.

Comment: Thank you! But why `default` cannot return different results for different rows? I've tried this but it always return same result for all rows?

Comment: Exactly because it's defined not to. It takes a single value and makes `defaultValueFun` return this value whenever it's called. If you want to ask _why_ it's defined this way, you have to ask the authors.

Comment: Also it would make sense to have something like a separate `defaultNow()` function but I don't know if it exists.

Comment: whenever `datetime("updated_dt").default(DateTime.now())` is called, although `DateTime.now()`'s value is different for every times, it's still always return one same value?

Comment: No, of course. But it isn't called when you access the table later.

Comment: I can't understand what happened, when I use `default()` to create record, all row have same value, but if I change to use `clientDefault`, every thing will be fine

Comment: Like this image https://imgur.com/a/LwGevj4, the value of `updated_dt` column is always same for any record

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to explain in my answer. If you still don't understand, I don't see how to explain even clearer, sorry.